# nothing to migrate laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

why can not, and it appears nothing to migrate?

when migrate create table authors and books can be, but after the foreign key can not be

migrations add foreign :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('books', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')
                ->onDelete('restrict')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

use this :

```
php artisan migrate
```

and this :

```
php artisan migrate --path=app/database/migrations/2016_07_11_105204_add_foreign_key_to_books.php
```

still can not,

table books :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('amount')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

table author :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('authors', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

thanks for help..

Comment: If you added the migration manually, try `composer dumpautoload` to get it recognised.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem. i find a way. it's not official

1. first go to database. if you use mysql. there is **migration** table. see the migration table has ROW 
   just like your migration file name such as 2016_07_11_105204_books.
2. delete the ROW by delete command.
3. Delete or drop the books table.
4. then go to Command prompt. provide command `php artisan migrate` again.

it will works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4.2's [schema](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema) doesn't support updating columns. So you may do it this way (first drop it, then create it as foreign key):

```
Schema::table('books', function(Blueprint $table) {
{
    $table->dropColumn('author_id');
    $table->integer('author_id')->after('title')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')
            ->onDelete('restrict')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For start migration call command with `--path` option which have only directories path.

```
php artisan migrate --path=app/database/migrations
```

You set `-path` with filename.